# I get an error when I use opencv(python) for drawing a bounding box on an image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

environments:

> python： 3.6.3
>
> opencv:  3.4.2
>
> windows 10

I want to draw a bounding box om an image, code as follows:

```
def draw_rect(img, bboxes):
    # img = img.copy()
    for bbox in list(bboxes[:, :4]):
        bbox = [int(float(co)) for co in bbox]
        bbox[2] += bbox[0]
        bbox[3] += bbox[1]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (bbox[0], bbox[1]), (bbox[2], bbox[3]), (0, 255, 0), 4)
    cv2.imshow('hh', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

img = cv2.imread(r'E:\dataset\steel\train_dataset\0B4F3CC3.jpg')

bboxes = [[123, 124, 500, 500], [200, 200, 400, 400]]
# img = img[:, :, ::-1]   # simple transform

draw_rect(img, np.array(bboxes))
```

this code works fine, but when I give a simple transform before draw bbox.

```
def draw_rect(img, bboxes):
    # img = img.copy()
    for bbox in list(bboxes[:, :4]):
        bbox = [int(float(co)) for co in bbox]
        bbox[2] += bbox[0]
        bbox[3] += bbox[1]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (bbox[0], bbox[1]), (bbox[2], bbox[3]), (0, 255, 0), 4)
    cv2.imshow('hh', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

img = cv2.imread(r'E:\dataset\steel\train_dataset\0B4F3CC3.jpg')

bboxes = [[123, 124, 500, 500], [200, 200, 400, 400]]


img = img[:, :, ::-1]   # simple transform


draw_rect(img, np.array(bboxes))
```

run above code, only an image shows on window, no any bbounding box.

but when I add code `img = img.copy()` as follows:

```
def draw_rect(img, bboxes):
    img = img.copy()
    for bbox in list(bboxes[:, :4]):
        bbox = [int(float(co)) for co in bbox]
        bbox[2] += bbox[0]
        bbox[3] += bbox[1]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (bbox[0], bbox[1]), (bbox[2], bbox[3]), (0, 255, 0), 4)
    cv2.imshow('hh', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

img = cv2.imread(r'E:\dataset\steel\train_dataset\0B4F3CC3.jpg')

bboxes = [[123, 124, 500, 500], [200, 200, 400, 400]]
img = img[:, :, ::-1]   # simple transform

draw_rect(img, np.array(bboxes))
```

everything going well. so what is the reason causing this phenomenon?

Comment: I've seen something similar recently with a different numpy function. The numpy arrays appear to be more flexible in regard of the data layout and how it can be indexex (specifically you can have negative stride to allow O(1) mirroring of individual axis). `cv::Mat` doesn't support that, and some functionality then misbehaves. Copying will cause a new array to be created with a "normal" layout.

Comment: I totally agree with @DanMašek. I encountered these effects very often when using OpenCV together with numpy arrays. The easiest thing is to work on a deep copy (what you do). If you would like to use transforms the "save" way, try to use [OpenCV functions](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html)